# WPF assembly reference missing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a class call `BinaryImageConverter` implement `IValueConverter` in `Common.Tools`.

How can I call it in WPF?

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ProductsSource"/>
        <local:BinaryImageConverter x:Key="ImgConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `prefix` definition to the `Window`. For example if, the namespace of `BinaryImageConverter` is `KevNameSapce` and its assembly is `KevAssembly` then your xmal code would looks similar to below.

```
<Window xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KevNameSapce;assembly=KevAssembly">
    <Window.Resources> 
        ...
        <local:BinaryImageConverter x:Key="ImgConverter" /> 
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

You don't have to specify the `assembly` if the converter class is in the same project,

Comment: Thanks. I need to rebuilt project.